# how to select xcode version in fastlane when using github actions

Tags: ios

I am using fastlane in github actions to build my project, this is my github actions script:

```
name: Cruise-CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: macos-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: '12.x'
    - uses: subosito/flutter-action@v1
      with:
        flutter-version: '1.22.5'
    - name: Select Xcode version
      run: sudo xcode-select -s '/Applications/Xcode_12.1.app/Contents/Developer'
    - name: Bundle install
      run: cd ./ios && bundle install && bundle update fastlane
    - name: Install tools
      run: |
       flutter precache
       flutter pub get
       cd ./ios && pod repo update && pod install
    #- run: flutter pub get
    #- run: flutter build apk
    #- run: flutter build ios --release --no-codesign
    - name: Setup SSH Keys and known_hosts for fastlane match
      run: |
        SSH_PATH="$HOME/.ssh"
        mkdir -p "$SSH_PATH"
        touch "$SSH_PATH/known_hosts"
        echo "$PRIVATE_KEY" > "$SSH_PATH/id_rsa"
        chmod 700 "$SSH_PATH"
        ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
        chmod 600 "$SSH_PATH/known_hosts"
        chmod 600 "$SSH_PATH/id_rsa"
        eval $(ssh-agent)
        ssh-add "$SSH_PATH/id_rsa"
      env:
        PRIVATE_KEY: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
    - name: Deploy to TestFlight/PGY
      run: |
        cd ./ios && bundle exec fastlane beta
      env:
        APPLE_ID: ${{ secrets.APPLE_ID }}
        GIT_URL: ${{ secrets.GIT_URL }}
        PGY_USER_KEY: ${{ secrets.PGY_USER_KEY }}
        PGY_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.PGY_API_KEY }}
        TEAM_ID: ${{ secrets.TEAM_ID }}
        ITC_TEAM_ID: ${{ secrets.ITC_TEAM_ID }}
        FASTLANE_USER: ${{ secrets.FASTLANE_USER }}
        FASTLANE_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.FASTLANE_PASSWORD }}
        FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD }}
        FASTLANE_SESSION: ${{ secrets.FASTLANE_SESSION }}
        MATCH_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.MATCH_PASSWORD }}
        MATCH_KEYCHAIN_NAME: ${{ secrets.MATCH_KEYCHAIN_NAME }}
        MATCH_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.MATCH_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD }}
        DELIVER_ITMSTRANSPORTER_ADDITIONAL_UPLOAD_PARAMETERS: ${{ secrets.DELIVER_ITMSTRANSPORTER_ADDITIONAL_UPLOAD_PARAMETERS }}
```

and this is my Fastfile script:

```
update_fastlane

default_platform(:ios)

platform :ios do
  desc "Push a new beta build to pgy"
  before_all do
    ENV["CACHE_GIT_URL"] = ENV["GIT_URL"]
  end

  lane :beta do
    xcode_select('/Applications/Xcode_12.1.app')
    if is_ci
      create_keychain(
        name: ENV['MATCH_KEYCHAIN_NAME'],
        password: ENV["MATCH_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD"],
        default_keychain: true,
        unlock: true,
        timeout: 3600,
        lock_when_sleeps: false
      )
    end

    match(
      app_identifier: ENV["APP_IDENTIFIER"],
      git_url: ENV["GIT_URL"],
      type: "adhoc",
      readonly: is_ci,
      keychain_name: ENV['MATCH_KEYCHAIN_NAME'],
      keychain_password: ENV["MATCH_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD"]
    )

    build_app(
        workspace: "Runner.xcworkspace",
        scheme: "Runner",
        export_method: "ad-hoc"
    )

    pgyer(
        api_key: ENV['PGY_API_KEY'],
        user_key: ENV['PGY_USER_KEY']
    )
  end
end
```

but when runs in github actions shows [this error](https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/cruise-open/runs/1739610932?check_suite_focus=true):

```
** ARCHIVE FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    PhaseScriptExecution Run\ Script /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gzzbtgmsqethlzedjqlbspydxjjv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Script-9740EEB61CF901F6004384FC.sh
(1 failure)
[04:51:35]: Exit status: 65
[04:51:35]: 
[04:51:35]: Maybe the error shown is caused by using the wrong version of Xcode
[04:51:35]: Found multiple versions of Xcode in '/Applications/'
[04:51:35]: Make sure you selected the right version for your project
[04:51:35]: This build process was executed using '/Applications/Xcode_12.1.app'
[04:51:35]: If you want to update your Xcode path, either
[04:51:35]: 
[04:51:35]: - Specify the Xcode version in your Fastfile
[04:51:35]: ▸ xcversion(version: "8.1") # Selects Xcode 8.1.0
[04:51:35]: 
[04:51:35]: - Specify an absolute path to your Xcode installation in your Fastfile
[04:51:35]: ▸ xcode_select "/Applications/Xcode8.app"
[04:51:35]: 
[04:51:35]: - Manually update the path using
[04:51:35]: ▸ sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app
[04:51:35]: 

+---------------+------------------------------+
|              Build environment               |
+---------------+------------------------------+
| xcode_path    | /Applications/Xcode_12.1.app |
| gym_version   | 2.171.0                      |
| export_method | ad-hoc                       |
| sdk           | iPhoneOS14.1.sdk             |
+---------------+------------------------------+

[04:51:35]: ▸ ../../../hostedtoolcache/flutter/1.22.5-stable/x64/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scroll_view.dart:588:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
[04:51:35]: ▸   const CustomScrollView({
[04:51:35]: ▸         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[04:51:35]: ▸ Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
[04:51:35]: 
[04:51:35]: ⬆️  Check out the few lines of raw `xcodebuild` output above for potential hints on how to solve this error
[04:51:35]:   For the complete and more detailed error log, check the full log at:
[04:51:35]:   /Users/runner/Library/Logs/gym/Runner-Runner.log
[04:51:35]: 
[04:51:35]: Looks like fastlane ran into a build/archive error with your project
[04:51:35]: It's hard to tell what's causing the error, so we wrote some guides on how
[04:51:35]: to troubleshoot build and signing issues: https://docs.fastlane.tools/codesigning/getting-started/
[04:51:35]: Before submitting an issue on GitHub, please follow the guide above and make
[04:51:35]: sure your project is set up correctly.
[04:51:35]: fastlane uses `xcodebuild` commands to generate your binary, you can see the
[04:51:35]: the full commands printed out in yellow in the above log.
[04:51:35]: Make sure to inspect the output above, as usually you'll find more error information there
[04:51:35]: 
+------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|                                        Lane Context                                         |
+------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| DEFAULT_PLATFORM                   | ios                                                    |
| PLATFORM_NAME                      | ios                                                    |
| LANE_NAME                          | ios beta                                               |
| KEYCHAIN_PATH                      | ~/Library/Keychains/***                     |
| ORIGINAL_DEFAULT_KEYCHAIN          | "/Users/runner/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db"    |
| SIGH_PROFILE_TYPE                  | ad-hoc                                                 |
| MATCH_PROVISIONING_PROFILE_MAPPING | {"com.earth.dolphin"=>"match AdHoc com.earth.dolphin"} |
+------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
[04:51:35]: Error building the application - see the log above
```

I have already tried to specify the version of xcode in fastlane file like this:

```
xcode_select('/Applications/Xcode_12.1.app')
```

but still not work, what should I do to fix this? I also tried to change the xcode version to 12.3 follow [this doc](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/macos/macos-10.15-Readme.md) like this:

```
xcode_select('/Applications/Xcode_12.3.app')
```

still now work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are running on the latest MacOS image (which, at time of writing, is `macos-10.15` with Xcode `12.4.0.0.1.1610135815`—see [installed tools](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/macos/macos-10.15-Readme.md#tools)):

```yaml
 jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: macos-latest
```

But you are trying to select a specific version of Xcode to use:

```yaml
- name: Select Xcode version
      run: sudo xcode-select -s '/Applications/Xcode_12.1.app/Contents/Developer'
```

The latest MacOS version (and the installed Xcode version) are liable to change if you use the `-latest` suffix when specifying the `runs-on` image.

Ensure that your MacOS and Xcode versions are compatible or just remove the `Select Xcode version` step entirely.